# Not able to call/run ajax in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have created Jquery Ajax in CodeIgniter to call same value.
Below code.
**index.php = View**

```
    <!-- JK Start -->                
    <div id="hide-table">
    <form action="" method="">
    <select id="fee_group">
    <?php
    $fee_group = $this->db->get("feegroup"); #fetching all the values from feegroup table to get related fee structure
    $details = $fee_group->result();
    foreach ($details as $d) {
        echo "<option value='".$d->feegroupID."'>".$d->name."</option>";
    }
     ?>
    </select>
    </form>
     <div id="record">
     </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JK Over -->   
        </div><!-- ./wrapper -->
<script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#fee_group").on("change",function(){
                          var view_permissions = $("#fee_group").val();
                          alert(view_permissions);
                          $.ajax({                        
                              type:"post",
                              url:"http://sample.in/school/feemonths/record",
                              data:"view_permissions="+view_permissions,
                              success:function(msg){
                                 $("#record").html(msg);
                              }

                          });

                    });
               });

       </script>
```

**fee_m.php =  controller**

```
public function record()
    {
        echo "this is sample data";
    }
```

When I click or select a value nothing return. Url is correct I saw while calling it directly.

Comment: is there any error in your console ?

Comment: @JYoThI: No error in console.

Comment: onchange `alert(view_permissions);`  it's alerting ?

Comment: @JYoThI: No its not returning anything.

Comment: i think your not getting my comment . first of all it's alerting or not before calling ajax . you put  `alert(view_permissions);` this one ?   2nd : did you included a the jquery library ?

Comment: @JYoThI: No dear it's not alerting.

Comment: did you included  the jquery library ?

Comment: @JYoThI: No I have not included the library. But after your comment i added the Library <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> but My application stopped working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150592/discussion-between-jyothi-and-jasshh-andrews).

Comment: i Think you have parse error . can you update your post  with current code